# Quickblox avatar for chat

Tags: android, quickblox

I'm interested in supplying chat-users with an avatar. I've looked through the API (chat, users, content) and could not find a solution.
The user object doesn't have the 'avatar' field - so no luck here.
The content object (uploading and browsing photos) allows a user to only search for his uploaded content (as far as I know), but there is a 'public' field in that object so there has to be some way to get e.g. content with name 'avatar' for user with id 'xxxx', right?

Same question could go for additional user details (adrress, age, etc.)

Could anyone provide any tips on how to achieve that? Android example (or even REST) will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each User has field **blob_id** http://quickblox.com/developers/Users#Response_3

This is a link to file in Content module,
So you can upload image to Content module and connect it to User through **blob_id** field

Comment: Great, thanks for the answer. But what if I want the user to have more properties visible by other users (age, city, etc.)? Should the **blob_id** point to a Custom Object?

Comment: You can create class e.g. UserExtraProfile in CustomObjects.
And write to it your user's extra fields.

Other users can read you user's extra fields using 'user_id' field as a filter for GET query